# Docker on Synology path /proc is mounted on /proc but it is not a shared or slave mount

Tags: docker, synology

On my home NAS (Synology DS923+), I run node-exporter via Docker (Synology OS is weird and I don't want to figure it out). After an OS upgrade (currently running `DSM 7.2-64570 Update 1`) I noticed that it was no longer running. Trying to run the container manually revealed that I was getting this error when trying to spawn the container:

```
Error response from daemon: path /proc is mounted on /proc but it is not a shared or slave mount
```

Initially I was trying to spawn the container using docker-compose, but I simplified it down to using `docker run` to remove docker-compose as a variable.

```bash
$ sudo docker run --net="host" --pid="host" -v "/:/host:ro,rslave" prom/node-exporter:v1.5.0 --path.rootfs=/host
docker: Error response from daemon: path / is mounted on / but it is not a shared or slave mount.
```

I've searched this error message, and there are a lot of references to this issue cropping up either in kubernetes or on Docker Desktop, I don't believe either one of those apply to me, as I'm running Docker Engine directly on a Linux host and not using k8s.

Here's my docker/compose versions and system mount table. Is there something about my setup that's going to prevent me from doing this, or can I work around this and run node-exporter in Docker somehow?

```
$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.23
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.1
 Git commit:        876964a
 Built:             Wed Jun 14 06:00:26 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.23
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.1
  Git commit:       5fcb1cf
  Built:            Wed Jun 14 06:00:58 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.6.15
  GitCommit:        b23a389d8c181697302d163356e97dec04eb8d88
 runc:
  Version:          v1.1.4
  GitCommit:        5af893d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        ed96d00

$ docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.9.0-6413-g38f6acd

$ sudo mount
/dev/md0 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=1988388k,nr_inodes=497097,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/synomonitor type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=synomonitor)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /proc/bus/usb type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=1988388k,nr_inodes=497097,mode=755)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/cachedev_0 on /volume1 type btrfs (rw,nodev,relatime,ssd,synoacl,space_cache=v2,auto_reclaim_space,metadata_ratio=50,block_group_cache_tree,syno_allocator,subvolid=256,subvol=/@syno)
none on /config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/cachedev_0 on /volume1/@docker type btrfs (rw,nodev,relatime,ssd,synoacl,space_cache=v2,auto_reclaim_space,metadata_ratio=50,block_group_cache_tree,syno_allocator,subvolid=256,subvol=/@syno)
/dev/mapper/cachedev_0 on /volume1/@docker/btrfs type btrfs (rw,nodev,relatime,ssd,synoacl,space_cache=v2,auto_reclaim_space,metadata_ratio=50,block_group_cache_tree,syno_allocator,subvolid=256,subvol=/@syno)
nsfs on /run/docker/netns/default type nsfs (rw)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/proc` filesystem was not mounted as shared, remounting fixes this.

```
$ mount --make-rshared /proc
```